# Is there any possible ways to implement Apple Pay on Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, applepay, flutter-3.0, applepay-web

Note: I have already implemented Apple Pay on mobile successfully, but there are not any useful resources to integrate **Apple Pay** with **Flutter Web**.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple_pay_on_the_web.

Comment: I have taken a look into apple pay documentation, but there are no clear steps to follow to implement apple pay with Flutter Web. All the available implementations are provided in javascript only for the Web.

Comment: Payment Request API is available through https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/dart-html-library.html.

Comment: @KarimHesham have you successfully implemented apple pay on flutter weB?

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ Not yet actually, I still cannot find a useful resource or reference, so I have it on hold. If you managed to find anything useful I will be glad if you could share

Comment: I am trying stripe on flutter web, but there is also no resource for flutter web. only available for android and ios.
I really don't get why google is not working for flutter web.
flutter web is on stable mode for the past 1.5 years+ but still, there is no good response for flutter web.

Comment: in stripe apple pay and Gpay is there but they charge extra for that. @KarimHesham

Comment: @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ Yeah, this really sounds weird why there is not any useful resources on the subject. Unfortunately, I am not looking into using Stripe at least in the meantime. I'll probably be trying to look for some workaround by implementing Apple Pay using Javascript and try to integrate it with the Flutter app.

Comment: Any update on this in 2023?